# Gitlab CI to deliver files to a remote server (rsync)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm working with SVN but I would like to move on to Git, and more specifically to Gitlab.

I have the following structure:

```
MyStructure/
  customer/
    client1/
      delivery.sh
      MyFiletoSend.sh
    client2/
      delivery.sh
      MyFiletoSend2.sh
```

Currently, the "delivery.sh" will send the modifications (rsync) of the file "MyFiletoSend.sh" to the server "client1".

Can I run the "delivery.sh" via Gitlab automatically after/before the git push only on the files modified in this push?

Example:

- I have a modification to make to the file "MyFiletoSend.sh" from client1/
- I make my change
- commit and push
- Gitlab is running "delivery.sh" on my "client1/" file.
- The file "MyFiletoSend.sh" is sent to the server of "client1" without touching "client2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible

but first of all you need to understand how gitlab ci works. Read this article https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/

You will create a step in your pipeline that will do what you want after you push the code (in master or in any other branch/mr)

and about the job? you have to create one, you can use this code to help you
https://gist.github.com/hnlq715/6c222ba0fd868bae7e4dfd3af61bf26e

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your delivery.sh scripts have all the rsync logic required, GitLab has built-in logic to detect changes in files and execute bash commands in response. You can create a separate job for each client, which can run in parallel in the same stage. This approach is also auditable in that it will clearly show you which clients got updated and with which version of the file.

```yaml
update-client-1:
  stage: update-clients
  only:
    changes:
      # Detect change only in MyFiletoSend.sh:
      - customer/client1/MyFiletoSend.sh
      # Detect any change in the customer folder:
      - customer/client1/*
  script:
      - cd customer/client1
      - delivery.sh

update-client-2:
  stage: update-clients
  only:
    changes:
      - customer/client2/*
  script:
      - cd customer/client2
      - delivery.sh


# repeat for all remaining clients
```

For more information: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges